# Add score when i eats my second apple in wormy.py

Tags: python

I am trying to edit the wormy.py code so there spawn 2 apples on a random location. But my problem is that if my worm eats the second apple the score won't go up. The score is counting up by looking at the worms lengt. Here's my code:

```
import random, pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

FPS = 12
WINDOWWIDTH = 1200
WINDOWHEIGHT = 600
CELLSIZE = 20
assert WINDOWWIDTH % CELLSIZE == 0, "Window width must be a multiple of 
cell size."
assert WINDOWHEIGHT % CELLSIZE == 0, "Window height must be a multiple of 
cell size."
CELLWIDTH = int(WINDOWWIDTH / CELLSIZE)
CELLHEIGHT = int(WINDOWHEIGHT / CELLSIZE)

#             R    G    B
WHITE     = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK     = (  0,   0,   0)
PURPLE    = (128,   0, 128)
GREEN     = (  0, 255,   0)
PINK      = (255,  51, 204) 
DARKGREEN = (  0, 155,   0)
DARKGRAY  = ( 40,  40,  40)
BGCOLOR = PINK

UP = 'up'
DOWN = 'down'
LEFT = 'left'
RIGHT = 'right'

HEAD = 0 # syntactic sugar: index of the worm's head

def main():
    global FPSCLOCK, DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT

    pygame.init()
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 18)
    pygame.display.set_caption('Wormy')

    showStartScreen()
    while True:
        runGame()
        showGameOverScreen()


def runGame():
    # Set a random start point.
    startx = random.randint(5, CELLWIDTH - 6)
    starty = random.randint(5, CELLHEIGHT - 6)
    wormCoords = [{'x': startx,     'y': starty},
                  {'x': startx - 1, 'y': starty},
                  {'x': startx - 2, 'y': starty}]
    direction = RIGHT

    # Start the apple in a random place.
    apple = getRandomLocation()

    # Start the apple2 in a random place.
    apple2 = getRandomLocation()

    while True: # main game loop
        for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop
            if event.type == QUIT:
                terminate()
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_LEFT or event.key == K_a) and direction != RIGHT:
                direction = LEFT
            elif (event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_d) and direction != LEFT:
                direction = RIGHT
            elif (event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_w) and direction != DOWN:
                direction = UP
            elif (event.key == K_DOWN or event.key == K_s) and direction != UP:
                direction = DOWN
            elif event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                terminate()

    # check if the worm has hit itself or the edge
    if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == -1 or wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == CELLWIDTH or wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == -1 or wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == CELLHEIGHT:
        return # game over
    for wormBody in wormCoords[1:]:
        if wormBody['x'] == wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] and wormBody['y'] == wormCoords[HEAD]['y']:
            return # game over

    # check if worm has eaten an apply
    if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == apple['x'] and wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == apple['y']:
        # don't remove worm's tail segment
        apple = getRandomLocation() # set a new apple somewhere

    # check if worm has eaten an apply2
    if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == apple2['x'] and wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == apple2['y']:
        # don't remove worm's tail segment
        apple2 = getRandomLocation() # set a new apple2 somewhere    

    else:
        del wormCoords[-1] # remove worm's tail segment

    # move the worm by adding a segment in the direction it is moving
    if direction == UP:
        newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] - 1}
    elif direction == DOWN:
        newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'], 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] + 1}
    elif direction == LEFT:
        newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] - 1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
    elif direction == RIGHT:
        newHead = {'x': wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] + 1, 'y': wormCoords[HEAD]['y']}
    wormCoords.insert(0, newHead)
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
    drawGrid()
    drawWorm(wormCoords)
    drawApple(apple)
    drawApple(apple2)
    drawScore(len(wormCoords) - 3)
    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)

def drawPressKeyMsg():
pressKeySurf = BASICFONT.render('Press a key to play.', True, DARKGRAY)
pressKeyRect = pressKeySurf.get_rect()
pressKeyRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 200, WINDOWHEIGHT - 30)
DISPLAYSURF.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)


def checkForKeyPress():
if len(pygame.event.get(QUIT)) > 0:
    terminate()

keyUpEvents = pygame.event.get(KEYUP)
if len(keyUpEvents) == 0:
    return None
if keyUpEvents[0].key == K_ESCAPE:
    terminate()
return keyUpEvents[0].key


def showStartScreen():
titleFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 100)
titleSurf1 = titleFont.render('Wormy!', True, WHITE, DARKGREEN)
titleSurf2 = titleFont.render('Wormy!', True, GREEN)

degrees1 = 0
degrees2 = 0
while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
    rotatedSurf1 = pygame.transform.rotate(titleSurf1, degrees1)
    rotatedRect1 = rotatedSurf1.get_rect()
    rotatedRect1.center = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT / 2)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(rotatedSurf1, rotatedRect1)

    rotatedSurf2 = pygame.transform.rotate(titleSurf2, degrees2)
    rotatedRect2 = rotatedSurf2.get_rect()
    rotatedRect2.center = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT / 2)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(rotatedSurf2, rotatedRect2)

    drawPressKeyMsg()

    if checkForKeyPress():
        pygame.event.get() # clear event queue
        return
    pygame.display.update()
    FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)
    degrees1 += 3 # rotate by 3 degrees each frame
    degrees2 += 7 # rotate by 7 degrees each frame


def terminate():
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()


def getRandomLocation():
return {'x': random.randint(0, CELLWIDTH - 1), 'y': random.randint(0, CELLHEIGHT - 1)}


def showGameOverScreen():
gameOverFont = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 150)
gameSurf = gameOverFont.render('Game', True, WHITE)
overSurf = gameOverFont.render('Over', True, WHITE)
gameRect = gameSurf.get_rect()
overRect = overSurf.get_rect()
gameRect.midtop = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, 10)
overRect.midtop = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, gameRect.height + 10 + 25)

DISPLAYSURF.blit(gameSurf, gameRect)
DISPLAYSURF.blit(overSurf, overRect)
drawPressKeyMsg()
pygame.display.update()
pygame.time.wait(500)
checkForKeyPress() # clear out any key presses in the event queue

while True:
    if checkForKeyPress():
        pygame.event.get() # clear event queue
        return

def drawScore(score):
    scoreSurf = BASICFONT.render('Score: %s' % (score), True, WHITE)
    scoreRect = scoreSurf.get_rect()
    scoreRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 120, 10)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(scoreSurf, scoreRect)


def drawWorm(wormCoords):
    for coord in wormCoords:
        x = coord['x'] * CELLSIZE
        y = coord['y'] * CELLSIZE
        wormSegmentRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE)
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGREEN, wormSegmentRect)
        wormInnerSegmentRect = pygame.Rect(x + 4, y + 4, CELLSIZE - 8, CELLSIZE - 8)
    pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, GREEN, wormInnerSegmentRect)


def drawApple(coord):
x = coord['x'] * CELLSIZE
y = coord['y'] * CELLSIZE
appleRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, CELLSIZE, CELLSIZE)
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, PURPLE, appleRect)


def drawGrid():
for x in range(0, WINDOWWIDTH, CELLSIZE): # draw vertical lines
    pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (x, 0), (x, WINDOWHEIGHT))
for y in range(0, WINDOWHEIGHT, CELLSIZE): # draw horizontal lines
    pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, DARKGRAY, (0, y), (WINDOWWIDTH, y))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I know it's alot of code but i am afraid i am gonna miss some important code if i delet stuff. And for you guys to test it you need the full code. But i think the most is going on on the drawApple and drawScore.

Answer (score 0):

```
# check if worm has eaten an apply
if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == apple['x'] and wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == apple['y']:
    # don't remove worm's tail segment <<< THIS COMMENT LIES
    apple = getRandomLocation() # set a new apple somewhere

# check if worm has eaten an apply2
if wormCoords[HEAD]['x'] == apple2['x'] and wormCoords[HEAD]['y'] == apple2['y']:
    # don't remove worm's tail segment
    apple2 = getRandomLocation() # set a new apple2 somewhere    

else:
    del wormCoords[-1] # remove worm's tail segment
```

Here we can see the first if-condition do not use the else.
Only if the `apple2` is not et do we remove the tail; no matter what happens to the other `apple`.

The difference is the `else:` part, which the first line i cited does not affect. By using an `elif` (else if) instead of the second `if` we can be sure that only one of the three options are entered (instead of as now sometimes doing both the apple = getRandom and the del wormCoords). Refer to [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

Comment: What do you mean by this comment LIES and how can i fix it?

Comment: What happens if the first if condition is true (the snake head is on the first apple)? How are we prevented from removing the tail segment? Remember that the `else` is selected only if the previous `if` is false.

Comment: So, there is no way to fix it?

Comment: There is a way to fix it, probably only one word away. Do you understand what the issue is? Say that the apples are not on the same location, and that the snake head is on apple 1. Then we enter the first if-block and we get a new random location for  the apple. Next we check the secod if-condition and see that, "no, we are not on apple2", so go to the else-block. There we remove the tail of the worm, making it shorter again.

Comment: I am not really sure what the issue is?(just started python by starting to edit an existing code and trying to understand it like changing colors and text, but now i wanna start working: for example the apple2) What i know is that the score is not being updated cause of when the worm eats an apple, but when the tail gets longer the score updates. (What i think of reading the code "drawScore(len(wormCoords) - 3)"). But why doesn't the snake get longer if it eats apple 2?

Comment: I do not really understand the comment. The snake array does get longer when `apple2` is eaten, not when `apple` is - for 2 it should work fine. The difference is the `else:` part, which the first line i cited does not affect. By using an `elif` (else if) instead of the second `if` we can be sure that only one of the three options are entered (instead of as now sometimes doing both the `apple = getRandom` and the `del wormCoords`). Refer to https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. It worked and i now have 2 workings apples. But i was wondering if i could make both apples get a score of 2? by adding 2 wormsegmets when it eats an apple. Is it possible to do that, and how should i start, in wich part of the code?

Comment: I would wonder where you would add the segments to start. What is meant to happen during one step? I think that you can accept an answer if it answered your question - and then ask a new question in a separate post?

Comment: Totally thank for your help. I am gonna try and figure it out by mysself. I may make a post later this week. Your tips helped me understand the problem and it is working right now.

Comment: Good luck with your projects!